# How can modify transformation in material design js file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows

I have cloned this repository [material design](https://github.com/material-components/material-web/tree/main)

In the catalog folder of this project [catalog](https://github.com/material-components/material-web/blob/main/catalog/scripts/copy-docs.mjs), at the path of /scripts/copy-docs.mjs, the following command found matches.

```
const transforms = [
  // catalog-only code comments are removed
  {
    before: /<!-- catalog-only-start -->(\n)*?<!--\s*/gm,
    after: '',
  },
  {
    before: /\s*-->(\n)*?<!-- catalog-only-end -->/gm,
    after: '',
  },
  // removes everything in between github-only-start and github-only-end
  // comments
  {
    before: /\s*<!-- no-catalog-start -->(.|\n)*?<!-- no-catalog-end -->\s*/gm,
    after: '\n\n',
  },
  // eleventy pages end with `/` so `components/checkbox.md` will turn into the
  // url `/components/checkbox`. Thus we need to transform the relative
  // `./images` links to `../images`.
  {
    before: /images\//gm,
    after: '../images/',
  },
];

async function fileIncludeTransform(filepath, fileContents) {
  const catalogIncludeRegex = /<!--\s?catalog-include "(.+)"\s?-->/g;
  const matches = [];
  let match = catalogIncludeRegex.exec(fileContents);

  // Collect all the regex matches
  while (match) {
    matches.push(match);
    match = catalogIncludeRegex.exec(fileContents);
  }

  const fileDir = dirname(filepath);

  // Iterate through the regex matches backward and splice in the file contents.
  // Iterating backwards so that injecting won't affect match string indices.
  for (let i = matches.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    const match = matches[i];
    const matchedString = match[0];
    const includePath = match[1];

    console.log(`Injecting ${includePath} file contents into ${filepath}...`);
    const includeContents = await readFile(join(fileDir, includePath), 'utf8');

    fileContents = fileContents.slice(0, match.index) + includeContents +
        fileContents.slice(match.index + matchedString.length);
  }

  return fileContents;
}

async function transformReadmes(filepaths, outdir = '', replacements = []) {
  const readmePromises = filepaths.map(async (entry) => {
    let readme = await readFile(entry, 'utf8');
    console.log(`Transforming ${entry}`);

    transforms.forEach((transform) => {
      readme = readme.replaceAll(transform.before, transform.after);
    });

    readme = await fileIncludeTransform(entry, readme);

    // The `components/<component-name>.md` path.
    let localPath = relative(join('..', 'docs'), entry);

    for (const [pattern, replacement] of replacements) {
      const regex = new RegExp(pattern);
      localPath = localPath.replace(regex, replacement);
    }


    // The output path at
    // /catalog/site/components/<?local path>/<component name>.md
    const outputPath = join('site', outdir, localPath);

    console.log(`Writing trasnformed file to: ${outputPath}`);
    return writeFile(outputPath, readme);
  });

  await Promise.all(readmePromises);
}
```

When i build the project, these pieces of codes does not remove specific comments from found files. I have this problem in windows, not linux based systems. ( match array is empty always)
How can modify this transformation in windows?